# GData for iPhone release configuration problem

Tags: objective-c, configuration, compilation, gdata

I'm experimenting with [Dan Bourque's "iphone-gcal" project](http://code.google.com/p/iphone-gcal/), which seems an excellent intro to how to use the objective-c client library for the Google Data APIs, and everything's working really well... until I try to get it to work in release mode, when I get a load of errors such as -

Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_xmlFreeNode", referenced from:
-[GDataXMLNode dealloc] in GDataXMLNode.o
      -[GDataXMLElement removeChild:] in GDataXMLNode.o
      -[GDataXMLElement addChild:] in GDataXMLNode.o
      +[GDataXMLNode elementWithName:stringValue:] in GDataXMLNode.o
  "_xmlStrdup", referenced from:
      _StringCacheKeyRetainCallBack in GDataXMLNode.o
      +[GDataXMLElement fixQualifiedNamesForNode:graftingToTreeNode:] in GDataXMLNode.o
      -[GDataXMLDocument setCharacterEncoding:] in GDataXMLNode.o
      -[GDataXMLDocument setVersion:] in GDataXMLNode.o
      -[GDataXMLNode setStringValue:] in GDataXMLNode.o

I've tried putting /usr/include/libxml2 in the header search path (release), then linking to it in the "Link binaries with libraries" section of Build Phases (which allows it to compile at least - it then hangs on launch, saying "Waiting for process 'GTUG Demo' to launch"), and a mixture of these, but no joy.

I've been scouring the docs & SO, etc, but nothing I do gets it to work. I realise I'm probably doing something stupid, but I'm losing too much hair over this! Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

libxml2 must be linked in to the release target with the flag -lxml2 as described at

http://code.google.com/p/gdata-objectivec-client/wiki/BuildingTheLibrary

Comment: Thanks - I'd not found the bit about the "Other Linker Flags", that's sorted it! I thought I'd linked the libxml2, but I'd missed this step.